# which files are the ones I should upload to a host

Tags: html, css, gulp, bower

I learned to do a working environment based bower, from there install yoeman and gulp and materialize, I made a web page to root of all this, now I want to upload a host (like 000webhost or firebase) but I do not know which files are the ones I should upload

thx

Answer (score 1):

You should upload **everything except** `bower_components` directory since it's content is used only when you compile down the things using `gulp` on your local machine. Once all your source files are piped through `gulp`, they are not required on the destination location. None of those files is or should be used during a *http request*.

I don't know exactly what is your project's structure, but because you specified what you use (`bower`, `gulp`) then I can deduct.

So after `gulp` finishes it's work, you have a `public` directory where all your combined, minified and copied assets live. This is obviously needed on the server, in your markup, you should refer to those files, not the ones fetched by `bower` when you've done `bower install library1 --save`. `bower install library2 --save`.

Comment: The project's structure is NodeJs, I don't have a public directory, I have an "app" directory and in "bower_components" is where materialize, jquery and fonts are.

If I upload everything except "bower_components" how the host knows where is the index, if the index where be in app directory.

Thank you for your answer...